# Showing error ' ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected' in this SQL command

Tags: plsql

Here are my code.

```
Create OR Replace Procedure new_prof 
(
Pno IN VARCHAR2,
ProLast_Name IN VARCHAR2,
ProFirst_Name IN VARCHAR2,
Pro_rank IN VARCHAR2,
ProResearch_Specialty IN VARCHAR2,
Pro_DOB IN DATE,
Time_percentage DECIMAL
)
IS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO professors VALUES(Pno,ProLast_Name,ProFirst_Name,Pro_DOB,Pro_rank,ProResearch_Specialty,Time_percentage);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('New Professors'||Pno||'is successfully created');

END;
/
```

---Execute the code
EXECUTE new_prof('P0026','Ronaldo','Christiano',TO_DATE('07/25/1978','MM/DD/YYYY'),'Senior','Programming',0.40);

After I excute this code, it show me  "the non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected" at the Date there.

Answer (score 0):

Sry, I have edit my title become a new question.